# use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, templates

I moved out the methods implementation from my class and caught the following error:

> Use of class template requires template argument list

for a method which doesn't require any template type at all… (for other methods everything is okay)

Class

```
template<class T>
class MutableQueue
{
public:
    bool empty() const;
    const T& front() const;
    void push(const T& element);
    T pop();

private:
    queue<T> queue;
    mutable boost::mutex mutex;
    boost::condition condition;
};
```

Wrong implementation

```
template<>   //template<class T> also incorrect
bool MutableQueue::empty() const
{
    scoped_lock lock(mutex);
    return queue.empty();
}
```

Comment: not relevant, but `queue<T> queue` is really weird naming convention... type name should be easily tell apart from instance name

Comment: I will follow your advice, but it is not a root cause

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It should be:

```
template<class T>
bool MutableQueue<T>::empty() const
{
    scoped_lock lock(mutex);
    return queue.empty();
}
```

And if your code is that short, just inline it, as you can't separate the implementation and header of a template class anyway.

Comment: `as you can't separate the implementation and header of a template class anyway`
Ahhhh.. +1

Comment: _"as you can't separate the implementation and header of a template class anyway"_. That is, unless you include the implementation at the end of the header with a preprocessor directive (`#include MutableQueue.tpp`)

Comment: "as you can't separate the implementation and header of a template class anyway" - or unless you explicitly instantiate it.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
template<class T>
bool MutableQueue<T>::empty() const
{
    ...
}
```