# use of class template requires template argument list for array

Tags: c++, templates

I have been at this two days now...

I am a beginner at c++, and am having trouble.

I will only put the minimum amount of code necessary.

```
template <typename Type>
class Array {
        public:

        *//stuff*

        Array operator= (Array const &);
};

template <typename Type>
Array& Array<Type>::operator=(Array const &rhs) {       //ERROR #1 here

*//stuff*

}                                                       //ERROR #2 here
```

I am getting the following 2 errors

'Array' : use of class template requires template argument list  
'Array::operator =' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Please help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [use of class template requires template argument list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477086/use-of-class-template-requires-template-argument-list)

Comment: @MohitJain No, it's not an exact duplicate. The error message is the same but the problem requires a different solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of the definition needs to be spelled out explicitly as `Array<Type> &`.  This is because the compiler doesn't know that you're in the context of an `Array<Type>` member definition until it sees `Array<Type>::`, so you can't use `Array` without template arguments until then.

```
template <typename Type>
Array<Type>& Array<Type>::operator=(Array const &rhs) {
//   ^^^^^^
```

Alternatively, you can use C++11's `auto` syntax to allow use of the `Array` name without template arguments, because this syntax specifies the return type *after* the compiler knows what context the definition is in.

```
template <typename Type>
auto Array<Type>::operator=(Array const &rhs) -> Array& {
//                                               ^^^^^^
// This works because the compiler has already encountered "Array<Type>::"
```

Comment: Thanks! Haven't learned C++11, so just went with the first part. It works

Answer (score 0):

for first error check this

```
Array<Type>& Array<Type>::operator==(Array<Type> const &rhs)
```

You cannot use just Array Array must have argmunets <>

in class

```
Array<Type> operator=(Array <Type> const &){}
```

Comment: You can use `Array` without type arguments *within the context of an `Array<T>` instantiation*, so you don't have to use it on the argument. (`Array const &` is perfectly valid there.) The issue is that the compiler doesn't yet know that we're in the context of an `Array<T>` instantiation until it sees `Array<Type>::` so the return type can't use this shortcut without C++11's `auto` return type.